# Error de SQL (1111): Invalid use of group function

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo una consulta MySQL para extraer los presupuestos del último año (el mayor año registrado en la tabla):

```
select *
from Presupuestos
where year(fecha) = max(year(fecha))
```

la columna fecha es de tipo DATE.

Al ejecutar la consulta me muestra:

> Error de SQL (1111): Invalid use of group function

¿Alguna solución? Gracias

Comment: hola a mi me da el mismo error pero con un Update, disculpar soy nueva en SQL Update magerit2.game set SCRACH = SUM(P1+P2+P3P4+P5+P6);

Answer (score 7):

Si intentas usar una función agregada en un contexto donde se espera una función no agregada, entonces recibes el error:

> Error de SQL (1111): Invalid use of group function

En tu caso particular, estás utilizando `YEAR()` en el bloque `WHERE`, que es un contexto en el que tal tipo de funciones no está permitido.

Para solucionarlo podrías utilizar `HAVING`, que sí permite funciones agregadas:

```
SELECT
     *
FROM
     Presupuestos
HAVING
     year(fecha) = max(year(fecha))
```

Referencia: [página wiki de este error en SO](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/mysql-error-1111/info)

Answer (score 1):

No puedes utilizar funciones como year() sum() o concat() en la parte de condiciones. Prueba

```
select max(year(fecha)) from Presupuestos;
```

[mysql year()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_year)

Answer (score 1):

He encontrado una solución

```
select *
from Presupuestos
where year(fecha) = (select max(year(fecha)) from Presupuestos)
```